# draw a linechart by reading excel data from excel file using javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is my excel file as follows==

Data

20.248602
18.54032
18.254036
15.217833
13.194518
17.521723
17.78833
24.018597
18.401508
24.46464
20.752457
22.570473
17.870035
22.474863
20.783422
24.075064
17.72947
20.202723
16.776543
19.087515
7.232176
8.508578
7.5457883
10.0660925
13.344348
5.5784864
5.3469315
17.087952

I'm trying to read exceldata from excel file and using those data i want to draw a line chart using javascript.but i can't figure it out how will i use the data to  draw a chart even though i read the exceldata from excel sheet without using ActiveXObject.Here is my code==

```
function Upload() 
{  
    var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");  
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;  
  if (regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) 
        {  
            if (typeof(FileReader) != "undefined") 
            {  
                var reader = new FileReader();  
                reader.onload = function(e) 
                {  
                    var table = document.createElement("table");  
                    var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");  
                    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) 
                        {  
                            var row = table.insertRow(-1);  
                            var cells = rows[i].split(",");  
                            for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) 

                            {  
                                var cell = row.insertCell(-1);  
                                cell.innerHTML = cells[j];  
                            }  
                        }  
                    var dvCSV = document.getElementById("dvCSV");  
                    dvCSV.innerHTML = "";
                    dvCSV.appendChild(table);

                //  dvCSV.appendChild("Workdate \t Data \t Status");  

                }  


            reader.readAsText(fileUpload.files[0]);  
        } 
        else 
            {  
                alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");  
            }  
} 
    else 
    {  
        alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");  
    }  
} 
</script> 
<body>
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
<input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" onclick = "Upload()" />
<hr />

<div id="dvCSV">

</div>
```

Please can anyone help me out...

Comment: http://d3js.org/ is the way to go...

Comment: is there any other way?@Akxe

Comment: Sure there is always an other way... Cou could learn with canvas and create the chart yourself...

Answer (score 2):

Here is another perspective on this problem, instead of reading an Excel file with JavaScript, you could directly use JavaScript in Excel with the help of the Funfun Excel add-in. Basically, Funfun is a tool that allows you to use JavaScript in Excel so you could use libraries like Chart.js to plot chart from the data in the spreadsheet.

First of all, you need to arrange your data a little bit to look like below.(I only took 10 of your data points as example)

[image]

Then, here are some steps to what you need to do to use JavaScript in Excel.

**1).** Insert the Funfun add-in from Office Add-ins store

[image]

**2).** Create a new Funfun or load a sample from Funfun online editor. If you creat a new funfun, you could write your own JavaScript code. In this case, I've already made a sample in Funfun online editor using JavaScript and Chart.js. You could directly load the code from the URL below.

https://www.funfun.io/1/edit/5a36a1ad45ac15144af3fdfd

[image]

**3).** Write JavaScrip code as you do in any other JavaScript editor. In this step, in order to directly use the data from the spreadsheet, you need to write some JSON I/O to make Excel cell reference. The place this value is in **Setting-short**. But this would be just several lines. For this case, the JSON I/O value would be:

```
{
    "data": "=B2:K2",
    "label": "=B1:K1"
}
```

You could check the Funfun documentation for more explanation.

**4).** Run the code to plot chart

Have fun:)

[image]

***Disclosure: I'm a developer of Funfun.***